# Can't link FFMPEG dynamically to VS 2019 project

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, visual-studio-2019

I downloaded the source code of FFMPEG 3.4.8 and built with MSVC as such:
After unzipping, open x86_x64 Cross Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019 and run `msys2_shell.cmd`. From there, run 
`./configure --toolchain=msvc --arch=x86_64 --enable-yasm --enable-asm --enable-shared --disable-static`
and
`make`

I then created a new project in VS 2019. 
In Properties > C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories: 
(Where all the headers are)

```
E:\ffmpeg-3.4.8\libavutil
E:\ffmpeg-3.4.8\libavcodec
E:\ffmpeg-3.4.8\libavdevice
E:\ffmpeg-3.4.8\libavfilter
E:\ffmpeg-3.4.8\libavresample
E:\ffmpeg-3.4.8\libpostproc
E:\ffmpeg-3.4.8\libswscale
E:\ffmpeg-3.4.8\libswresample
E:\ffmpeg-3.4.8\libavformat
```

In Properties > Linker > General > Additional Library Directories: 
(Where the .lib files are)

```
E:\ffmpeg-3.4.8\libavutil
E:\ffmpeg-3.4.8\libavcodec
E:\ffmpeg-3.4.8\libavdevice
E:\ffmpeg-3.4.8\libavfilter
E:\ffmpeg-3.4.8\libavresample
E:\ffmpeg-3.4.8\libpostproc
E:\ffmpeg-3.4.8\libswscale
E:\ffmpeg-3.4.8\libswresample
E:\ffmpeg-3.4.8\libavformat
```

In Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies:

```
avcodec.lib
avdevice.lib
avfilter.lib
avformat.lib
swresample.lib
swscale.lib
```

For good measure, I copied the .dll files of each library to the Release folder of the project. There is one source file I am trying to build and run:

```
extern "C" {
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
}

int main() {
    AVFormatContext* pFormatContext = avformat_alloc_context();
}
```

The result is as follows:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: FFMPEG_example, Configuration: Release x64 ------
1>Source.cpp
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol avformat_alloc_context
1>C:\Users\maya.s\source\repos\FFMPEG_example\x64\Release\FFMPEG_example.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "FFMPEG_example.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks!

Comment: IIRC, you need to write the libraries `libavcodec.lib` instead of `avcodec.lib`. MSVC build system unlike some other compilers/build systems doesn't add the "lib" in the beginning. P.S. are you sure that extern "C" is proper here?

Comment: @rustyx yes, you can see in the build output. @ALX23z the name of .lib file is as it appears in the folder. And `extern "C"` is necessary because the API is written in C and I am using C++.